# How should I alter the trainable parameters to increase validation accuracy of CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of office items consisting of 7 objects each having 10 images resulting in a dataset of 70 samples. (this data cannot be increased). The only pre-processing I am doing to the images is resizing and converting to monochrome. It can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nsMUPRVmtpNRXNc5bWsdYua2_Mb8FU1L?usp=sharing) along with its ground truth. I am trying to obtain a trained model, I tried to increase the convolution layers, add dropout after each layer, I tried different train-test splits but (80-20) seems to be the best option, I removed some dense layers such that I can decrease the trainable parameters given the small size of the dataset. I tried using Adam optimiser but SGD achieved better training accuracy, I also tried to increase/decrease learning rate and decay rate. Not sure what I should try next. I can change the model however I like as long as validation accuracy is increased.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

#dataset
x_train = glob.glob('Dataset/*/*.jpg', recursive=True)
print("Dataset size: ",len(x_train))

#ground truth 
y_train = glob.glob('ground_truth.csv', recursive=True)
print("Parameter size: ",len(y_train))

N = len(x_train)
imgs_all = np.zeros((N,112,112), dtype = np.float64) #This is a 3-D array containing zeros for the time being

for t in range(len(x_train)): 
    #LOAD IMAGES
    image = cv2.imread(x_train[t])
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image_resized_gray = cv2.resize(image_gray, (112, 112), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    imgs_all[t,:,:] = image_resized_gray

#GROUND TRUTH 
df = pd.read_csv("ground_truth.csv")

# initial ground truth
data = np.dstack((df["Path"], df["Name"], df["Item"], df["Ground_Truth"]))[0]
GTs = data[:, 3] #1D array with shape (70,)
GTs = np.expand_dims(GTs, axis=1)  #2D array with shape (70,1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(imgs_all, GTs, test_size=0.2) #80:20

y_train_cat = to_categorical(y_train,7)
y_test_cat = to_categorical(y_test,7)
x_train = x_train/255
x_test = x_test/255
x_train = x_train.reshape(56,112,112,1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(14,112,112,1)

model = Sequential()

#First set of convolutional and pooling layers
model.add(Conv2D(filters=6,kernel_size=(5,5),input_shape=(112,112,1),activation='relu', padding = 'valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides = 2))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

#Second set of convolutional and pooling layers
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', padding = 'valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides = 2))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

#maps 2d to 1d
model.add(Flatten())

# Dropout layer with probability of retention of p = 0.5
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#output layer
model.add(Dense(7,activation='softmax',name='output'))

print(model.summary())

# Load optimiser to configure parameters
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.03, decay= 1e-4)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train_cat,
                    batch_size = 4,
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_data=(x_test,y_test_cat))
```

The following is a summary of the model:

[image]

And the training/validation achieved after the last epoch:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental problem is that the number of samples (10) you have for each of your 7 classes is far to small. If you can not increase the size of the dataset then your next best choice is to use image augmentation to increase the number of image samples in each class. First create a dataframe with columns 'filepaths', 'labels' where the filepath column contains the full path to all the images and the labels column contains the class label of the associated image file. The use train_test_split to split the dataframe into a train_df, a test_df and a valid_df.
Then for train_df we will create augmented images for each class, store these images,
create a new datatrame (aig_df) and concatentate it with the original train_df.
The function below will accomplish that

```
def balance(train_df,max_samples, min_samples, column, working_dir, image_size):
    train_df=train_df.copy()        
    # make directories to store augmented images
    aug_dir=os.path.join(working_dir, 'aug')
    if os.path.isdir(aug_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(aug_dir)
    os.mkdir(aug_dir)
    for label in train_df['labels'].unique():    
        dir_path=os.path.join(aug_dir,label)    
        os.mkdir(dir_path)
    # create and store the augmented images  
    total=0
    gen=ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,  rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=.2,
                                  height_shift_range=.2, zoom_range=.2)
    groups=train_df.groupby('labels') # group by class
    for label in train_df['labels'].unique():  # for every class               
        group=groups.get_group(label)  # a dataframe holding only rows with the specified label 
        sample_count=len(group)   # determine how many samples there are in this class  
        if sample_count< max_samples: # if the class has less than target number of images
            aug_img_count=0
            delta=max_samples-sample_count  # number of augmented images to create
            target_dir=os.path.join(aug_dir, label)  # define where to write the images    
            aug_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe( group,  x_col='filepaths', y_col=None, target_size=image_size,
                                            class_mode=None, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, 
                                            save_to_dir=target_dir, save_prefix='aug-', color_mode='rgb',
                                            save_format='jpg')
            while aug_img_count<delta:
                images=next(aug_gen)            
                aug_img_count += len(images)
            total +=aug_img_count
    print('Total Augmented images created= ', total)
    # create aug_df and merge with train_df to create composite training set ndf
    if total>0:
        aug_fpaths=[]
        aug_labels=[]
        classlist=os.listdir(aug_dir)
        for klass in classlist:
            classpath=os.path.join(aug_dir, klass)     
            flist=os.listdir(classpath)    
            for f in flist:        
                fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)         
                aug_fpaths.append(fpath)
                aug_labels.append(klass)
        Fseries=pd.Series(aug_fpaths, name='filepaths')
        Lseries=pd.Series(aug_labels, name='labels')
        aug_df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)
        train_df=pd.concat([train_df,aug_df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
   
    print (list(train_df['labels'].value_counts()) )
    return train_df
```

now call the function as shown below

```
max_samples=75 # number of total samples in each class
min_samples=0
column = 'labels'
img_size=(224,224) # select an image size of the augmented images
working_dir=r'working_dir' # name of directory to store the augmented images
train_df=balance(train_df, max_samples, min_samples, column, working_dir, img_size)
```

train_df will end up with (75) images in each of your 7 classes. Now you can use train_df to train your model.

Comment: Won't I get an error if I call the function since train_df is not defined?

Comment: As I said use the sklearn function  train_test_split to split the original dataframe into a train_df, a test_df and a valid_df. Then augment the images in train_df using the balance function.